# What scripts does nmap Option -A use?

Tags: nmap

Can anyone answer which scripts are used when the `-A` flag is used?

The answers I've found all point to the generic `-A: Enables OS detection and Version detection, Script scanning and Traceroute.` help info which doesn't answer which scripts are used.

Is it equivalent to having `--script="(default and safe)"` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, it is identical.

You can verify this by looking at [`nmap.cc`](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap.cc), which parses the arguments. The handler for `-A` sets `delayed_options.advanced` to true, which in turn sets `o.script` to true. This is identical to the `-sC` flag, which also sets `o.script` to true.

As for which scripts are run, this depends on the nmap version. By default, it runs scripts that nmap considers "safe"

Comment: Thanks, It was just something I'd been wondering about, much appreciated

Comment: By default, Nmap runs scripts in the "default" category only.